# Esri Maps: Framework or control set for view Esri maps with SVG

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, svg, esri

Is there any control or framework to render [esri](http://www.esri.com/) maps in html5 SVG format?

I prefer the control to be in asp.net web forms, but plain javascript is also helpful.

thanks in advance